# How to run a NUnit test using cmd

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit

I created a simple test suite using NUnit by opening a new .Net console application project.

In the Visual Studio at Test explorer I can see my test methods.
Now I want to run them using CMD, i.e. at the command line prompt.

How do I going to do this?

[image]

These are my files inside the bin folder.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's hard to understand given your current description and this may lead to this question being closed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the NUnit with the installer this installs the executables in your PATH. Just using the NuGet packages won't work.

How to run from the command line is documentation in the NUnit documentation:

- 2.x: https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.7
- 3.x: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

Looks something like

```
 nunit3-console yourtest.dll
```

As an alternative you can look at the [NUnit light runner](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnitLite-Runner), this way you can build an .exe that will include everything to run the tests.